# How SQL Query to REPLACE all thumbnail size and set it to full size (WordPress)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Right now my code in wp_post / post_content is

```
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-150467" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/imagename-650x431.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="431">
```

I want to remove+change to be

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-150467" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/imagename.jpg" alt="">
```

- change size-large to size-full
- remove -650x431 (image size name suffix)
- remove width & height

Could you guys help SQL Query for this, please?

. . .

If SQL cannot make change all that,
Only remove 
`imagename-650x431.jpg`
(650 is fix but 431 is any number) -to-> 
`imagename.jpg`

I tried

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '-650x%.', '.');
```

But it won't work

It would be nice.

Big Thank You.

Comment: You can do that with an UPDATE query like so: `UPDATE table SET column = REAPLCE(column, 'size-large', 'size-full')` (untested of course). Depending on the table schema the query is only similar. Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried 

UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '-650x%.', '.');

But it wont work.

Comment: the fix string like 'size-large' I can replace it but the variable number like -650x% this one I cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
IPDATE Tablename SET columnname =  REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
   Columnname
,'size-large','size-full'),'width="650" height="431"',''),'-650x[0-9]+','');
```

This works like this:

> ```
> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
>    '<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-150467" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/imagename-650x431.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="431">'
> ,'size-large','size-full'),'width="650" height="431"',''),'-650x[0-9]+','');
> ```
>
> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
>    '<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-150467" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/imagename-650x431.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="431">'
> ,'size-large','size-full'),'width="650" height="431"','' |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-150467" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/imagename.jpg" alt="" >                                                                                                                                |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('"/2016/10/imagename-650x431.jpg" ','-650x[0-9]+','')
> ```
>
> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE('"/2016/10/imagename-650x431.jpg" ','-650x[0-9]+','') |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | "/2016/10/imagename.jpg"                                             |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c4097a70c69e2ae8e37692eb632bcfef)*

Result is:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-150467" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/imagename.jpg" alt="" >
```

Should the numbers change, the query would be more complicated, and you should also explain with mysql version you are using

Comment: Can '-650x431' use as '-650x%' ?

Comment: I using MariaDB 10.3

Comment: Ok that has more option than mysql 5.7 so try the new query on a test database.